# Need to get id using onClick event (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the id of the clicked element but typescipt doesn't support event.target.id.

It displays the whole div when I console.log(event.target) and doesn't allow me to use id.

Comment: You should try this `let elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access `event.target.id` because the `EventTarget` interface only implements a few properties.

See this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) for more information.

In order to access the `id` property, you will have to first cast `event.target` to `HTMLElement` or just `Element`.

Example:

```
document.onclick = (ev) => {
  if(ev.target !== null)
  console.log((ev.target as Element).id);
}
```